# Best way to ensure a PHP variable is an array

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have a javascript client passing a parameter to a server function (I'm using ExtJS Direct). Sometimes the client sends a single object, sometimes it sends an array of objects.

Currently I'm using this EnsureArray function to ensure the parameter is an array, and then I do `foreach`:

```
// Wraps a non array variable with an array.
function EnsureArray( &$aVar )
{
    if ( !is_array( $aVar ) )
        $var = array( $aVar );
}

function Destroy( $aRecords )
{
    // $aRecords might be a single object or an array of objects. Ensure it's wrapped as an array.        
    $this->EnsureArray( $aRecords );

    foreach ( $aRecords as $aRecord )
    {
        sql( "UPDATE Groups SET deleted = true WHERE id = $aRecord->id LIMIT 1" );
    }        

    return array(
        'success' => true,
    );
}
```

Is there a trick, neater way, one line that can do the same?

**Edit:** Since posting this question, I've found that ExtJS has [an option](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-allowSingle) to send all records wrapped in array.

Comment: The best way would be to standardize what the client is supposed to send... :)

Comment: I completely agree with this.

Comment: And consider fixing sql injections

Comment: Thanks @Venu. It's a closed system for a school, so not a prime concern.

Comment: @Izhaki be a sport an sanitize the input anyways. Being over confident will not ensure your app security!

Comment: You should use the allowSingle: false as writer in your proxy config
`proxy: { writer: { allowSingle: false } } `
so all your request will be arrays from ExtJS direct store

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following, instead of the function:

```
$aRecords = is_array($aRecords) ? $aRecords : array($aRecords);
```

Comment: That will not work if it's supposed to be an array of arrays!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the best way tbh, if you're not going to enforce that you're always being sent an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the function `Destroy` require arrays as its parameter:

```
function Destroy(array $aRecords) { ... }
```

The client should then also always send arrays. If, for whatever reason, that is not possible, the code that is receiving the (non-)array from the client and is passing it on to `Destroy()` needs to be responsible for passing it along as an array, because it's the interface between the (non-compliant) client and the standardized function.

There's probably going to be one endpoint for each possible action the client can call, so you don't even need to figure out whether the data is an array or not, you simply know. I.e.:

```
// someaction.php

include 'destroy.php';
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
Destroy($data);
```

but:

```
// anotheraction.php

include 'destroy.php';
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
Destroy(array($data));
```

If the client erratically sends different formats to the same action, fix the client.

Comment: Thanks for this response. It is very informative. As I'm using ExtJS Direct Package, and all the server calls are done automatically within a rather complex MVC framework, I'd rather not to patch ExtJS, particularly not the Direct package. The guys at Sencha sometimes have good reasons for how they implement things. I would offer the developer to consider making the calls consistant. I'd accept the answer most appropriate to the original question. Still, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Simply typecast the variable to an array:

```
function Destroy( $aRecords )
{
    foreach ( (array)$aRecords as $aRecord )
    {
        sql( "UPDATE Groups SET deleted = true WHERE id = $aRecord->id LIMIT 1" );
    }        

    return array(
       'success' => true,
    );
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: This is an elegant approach when you are dealing with a variable that is either an array or a primitive type, but it will fail horribly for objects. Per the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting), "If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties." Also, `(array)null` is the empty array which might or might not be what you want.